# Frequencies per factor in R using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to get the frequencies for each factor in my table, my current code is this:

```
frequencies <- dt[,c("Variable"), with=FALSE][
                  ,count := length(Variable), by=Variable][
                  ,list(total = sum(count)), by=Variable]
```

However this seems to be highly inefficient, so I was wondering can this be written more compact?

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
   Variable
1  Yes
2  No
3  Yes
4  No
5  Yes
```

it should return:

```
No  2
Yes 3
```

Comment: `dt[, .N, by = Variable]`? or `dt[, table(Variable)]` ?

Comment: Thank you David, please post it as an answer and I can give you points :). So simple, I was thinking too complicated.

Answer (score 5):

You could either use `.N`

```
dt[, .N, by = Variable]
#    Variable N
# 1:      Yes 3
# 2:       No 2
```

Or just `table`

```
dt[, table(Variable)]
# Variable
#  No Yes 
#   2   3
```

Or a more convenient format from `table`

```
dt[, as.data.table(table(Variable))]
#    Variable N
# 1:       No 2
# 2:      Yes 3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `summary` of a factor readily yields the frequencies of its different levels. So:

`myvar = factor(c('Yes','No','Yes','No','Yes')) ; t = summary(myvar)`

Comment: For this example, you probably should do `dt[, summary(Variable)]`. Though if `Variable` isn't a factor you'll need `dt[, summary(factor(Variable))]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Is there a way we donot lose the factor labels? The preference will be to get another column with factor labels so that we can dcast the data.table with rows converted to columns if needed.